# How to restore original object/type from JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

Its easy to load JSON into an object in javascript using eval or JSON.parse.

But if you have a proper "class" like function, how do you get the JSON data into it?

E.g.

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name=name;
  this.address = new Array();
  this.friendList;

  this.promote = function(){
     // do some complex stuff
  }
  this.addAddress = function(address) {
    this.address.push(address)
  }
}

var aPersonJSON = '{\"name\":\"Bob\",\"address\":[{\"street\":\"good st\",\"postcode\":\"ADSF\"}]}'

var aPerson = eval( "(" + aPersonJSON + ")" ); // or JSON.parse
//alert (aPerson.name);    // Bob
var someAddress = {street:"bad st",postcode:"HELL"};
//alert (someAddress.street); // bad st
aPerson.addAddress(someAddress); // fail!
```

The crux is I need to be able to create proper Person instances from JSON, but all I can get is a dumb object.  Im wondering if its possible to do something with prototypes?

I dont want to have to parse each line of the JSON and assign each variable to the coresponding functions attributes, which would be too difficult.  The actualy JSON and functions I have are much more complicated than the example above.

I am assuming one could JSONify the functions methods into the JSON string, but as I need to keep the resultant data as small as possible this is not an option - I only want to store and load the data, not the javascript code for the methods.

I also dont want to have to put the data loaded by JSON as a sub object if I can help it (but might be the only way), e.g.

```
function Person(name) {
  this.data = {};
  this.data.name=name;
}

var newPerson = new Person("");
newPerson.data = eval( "(" + aPersonJSON + ")" );
alert (newPerson.data.name); // Bob
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please use [`JSON.parse`](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/) and not `eval` to parse JSON. If the target browser(s) don't support `JSON.parse` (i.e. is IE7 or older), a shim via Crockford's `json.js` (which uses `eval` internally but also provides sanity validation) or `json2.js` is readily available.

Comment: Hi, The problem is not eval or parse, which both produce the same untyped object, I am trying to find a way to get the JSON into the Person fuction.  Any ideas on this?

Comment: @JohnLittle never use eval!, it is a source of many security issues (code injection etc.) [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil)

Comment: @thepoosh That is why it was a comment :) In any case, JSON is not "associated with a particular type of object". Two approaches are to add singleton methods or to copy (deeply, perhaps) the values from the JSON to a new object with the appropriate constructor function/[[prototype]].

Comment: Can't you just iterate over Objects and replace .prototype and constructor?

Answer (score 27):

You need to use a `reviver` function:

```
// Registry of types
var Types = {};

function MyClass(foo, bar) {
  this._foo = foo;
  this._bar = bar;
}
Types.MyClass = MyClass;

MyClass.prototype.getFoo = function() {
  return this._foo;
}

// Method which will provide a JSON.stringifiable object
MyClass.prototype.toJSON = function() {
  return {
    __type: 'MyClass',
    foo: this._foo,
    bar: this._bar
  };
};

// Method that can deserialize JSON into an instance
MyClass.revive = function(data) {
  // TODO: do basic validation
  return new MyClass(data.foo, data.bar);
};

var instance = new MyClass('blah', 'blah');

// JSON obtained by stringifying an instance
var json = JSON.stringify(instance); // "{"__type":"MyClass","foo":"blah","bar":"blah"}";

var obj = JSON.parse(json, function(key, value) {
  return key === '' && value.hasOwnProperty('__type')
    ? Types[value.__type].revive(value)
    : this[key];
});

obj.getFoo(); // blah
```

No other way really...

Comment: Is there a convention to call this function `reviver`?

Comment: In the spec for the JSON object, the method (and the formal argument) is referred to as a reviver.

Answer (score 6):

Many frameworks provide an 'extend' function that will copy fields over from one object to another. You can combine this with JSON.parse to do what you want.

```
newPerson = new Person();
_.extend(newPerson, JSON.parse(aPersonJSON));
```

If you don't want to include something like underscore you can always copy over just the extend function or write your own.

Coffeescript example because I was bored:

```
JSONExtend = (obj, json) ->
  obj[field] = value for own field, value of JSON.parse json
  return obj

class Person
  toString: -> "Hi I'm #{@name} and I'm #{@age} years old."


dude = JSONExtend new Person, '{"name":"bob", "age":27}'
console.log dude.toString()
```

Comment: At the risk of incurring miscellaneous wrath, +1 for Coffeescript!

Answer (score 6):

A little late to the party, but this might help someone.
This is how I've solved it, ES6 syntax:

```
class Page 
{
   constructor() {
      this.__className = "Page";
   }

   __initialize() {
       // Do whatever initialization you need here.
       // We'll use this as a makeshift constructor.
       // This method is NOT required, though
   }
}

class PageSection
{
   constructor() {
      this.__className = "PageSection";
   }
}

class ObjectRebuilder
{
    // We need this so we can instantiate objects from class name strings
    static classList() {
        return {
            Page: Page,
            PageSection: PageSection
        }
    }

    // Checks if passed variable is object.
    // Returns true for arrays as well, as intended
    static isObject(varOrObj) {
        return varOrObj !== null && typeof varOrObj === 'object';
    }

    static restoreObject(obj) {
        let newObj = obj;

        // At this point we have regular javascript object
        // which we got from JSON.parse. First, check if it
        // has "__className" property which we defined in the
        // constructor of each class
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty("__className")) {
            let list = ObjectRebuilder.classList();

            // Instantiate object of the correct class
            newObj = new (list[obj["__className"]]);

            // Copy all of current object's properties
            // to the newly instantiated object
            newObj = Object.assign(newObj, obj);

            // Run the makeshift constructor, if the
            // new object has one
            if (newObj.__initialize === 'function') {
                newObj.__initialize();
            }
        }

        // Iterate over all of the properties of the new
        // object, and if some of them are objects (or arrays!) 
        // constructed by JSON.parse, run them through ObjectRebuilder
        for (let prop of Object.keys(newObj)) {
            if (ObjectRebuilder.isObject(newObj[prop])) {
                newObj[prop] = ObjectRebuilder.restoreObject(newObj[prop]);
            }
        }

        return newObj;
    }
}

let page = new Page();
let section1 = new PageSection();
let section2 = new PageSection();

page.pageSections = [section1, section2];

let jsonString = JSON.stringify(page);
let restoredPageWithPageSections = ObjectRebuilder.restoreObject(JSON.parse(jsonString));

console.log(restoredPageWithPageSections);
```

Your page should be restored as an object of class `Page`, with array containing 2 objects of class `PageSection`. Recursion works all the way to the last object regardless of depth.

@Sean Kinsey's answer helped me get to my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to use `JSON.parse` to parse your string then pass the object to the function. `JSON.parse` is part of the json2 library online.

Comment: JSON methods are available in modern browsers...use library as fallback for older browsers

Comment: The `JSON.stringify()` function is **not** for *parsing*; it's for turning an object *into* a JSON string.

Comment: Hi, this is the crux, how to turn the resultant complex object intot he fuction?  You cant just pass it - unless I wrote something very complex to traverse the object, copying each sub-object and data item into the Person objeject which I dont want to have to do, especially as it changes frequently.

Answer (score 1):

**TL; DR:** This is approach I use:

```
var myObj = JSON.parse(raw_obj_vals);
myObj = Object.assign(new MyClass(), myObj);
```

Detailed example:

```js
const data_in = '{ "d1":{"val":3,"val2":34}, "d2":{"val":-1,"val2":42, "new_val":"wut?" } }';
class Src {
    val1 = 1;
    constructor(val) { this.val = val; this.val2 = 2; };
    val_is_good() { return this.val <= this.val2; }
    get pos_val() { return this.val > 0; };
    clear(confirm) { if (!confirm) { return; }; this.val = 0; this.val1 = 0; this.val2 = 0; };
};
const src1 = new Src(2); // standard way of creating new objects
var srcs = JSON.parse(data_in);
// ===================================================================
// restoring class-specific stuff for each instance of given raw data
Object.keys(srcs).forEach((k) => { srcs[k] = Object.assign(new Src(), srcs[k]); });
// ===================================================================

console.log('src1:', src1);
console.log("src1.val_is_good:", src1.val_is_good());
console.log("src1.pos_val:", src1.pos_val);

console.log('srcs:', srcs)
console.log("srcs.d1:", srcs.d1);
console.log("srcs.d1.val_is_good:", srcs.d1.val_is_good());
console.log("srcs.d2.pos_val:", srcs.d2.pos_val);

srcs.d1.clear();
srcs.d2.clear(true);
srcs.d3 = src1;
const data_out = JSON.stringify(srcs, null, '\t'); // only pure data, nothing extra. 
console.log("data_out:", data_out);
```

- Simple & Efficient. Compliant (in 2021). No dependencies.
- Works with incomplete input, leaving defaults instead of missing fields (particularly useful after upgrade).
- Works with excessive input, keeping unused data (no data loss when saving).
- Could be easily extended to much more complicated cases with multiple nested classes with class type extraction, etc.
- doesn't matter how much data must be assigned or how deeply it is nested (*as long as you restore from simple objects, see [Object.assign() limitations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#warning_for_deep_clone)*)

Answer (score 0):

I;m not too much into this, but aPerson.addAddress should not work,
why not assigning into object directly ?

```
aPerson.address.push(someAddress);
alert(aPerson.address); // alert [object object]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone needs it, here is a pure javascript extend function
(this would obviously belong into an object definition).

```
  this.extend = function (jsonString){
    var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString)
    for (var key in obj) {
        this[key] = obj[key]
        console.log("Set ", key ," to ", obj[key])
        }   
    }
```

Please don't forget to remove the `console.log` :P

Answer (score 0):

The modern approach (in December 2021) is to use `@badcafe/jsonizer` : https://badcafe.github.io/jsonizer

- Unlike other solutions, it doesn't pollute you data with injected class names,
- and it reifies the expected data hierarchy.
- below are some examples in Typescript, but it works as well in JS

Before showing an example with a class, let's start with a simple data structure :

```js
const person = {
    name: 'Bob',
    birthDate: new Date('1998-10-21'),
    hobbies: [
        {   hobby: 'programming',
            startDate: new Date('2021-01-01'),
        },
        {   hobby: 'cooking',
            startDate: new Date('2020-12-31'),
        },
    ]
}
const personJson = JSON.stringify(person);
// store or send the data
```

Now, let's use Jsonizer

```js
// in Jsonizer, a reviver is made of field mappers :
const personReviver = Jsonizer.reviver<typeof person>({
    birthDate: Date,
    hobbies: {
        '*': {
            startDate: Date
        }
    }
});
const personFromJson = JSON.parse(personJson, personReviver);
```

Every dates string in the JSON text have been mapped to `Date` objects in the parsed result.

Jsonizer can indifferently revive JSON data structures (arrays, objects) or class instances with recursively nested custom classes, third-party classes, built-in classes, or sub JSON structures (arrays, objects).

Now, let's use a class instead :

```js
// in Jsonizer, a class reviver is made of field mappers + an instance builder :
@Reviver<Person>({ //   bind the reviver to the class
    '.': ({name, birthDate, hobbies}) => new Person(name, birthDate, hobbies), //   instance builder
    birthDate: Date,
    hobbies: {
        '*': {
            startDate: Date
        }
    }
})
class Person {
    constructor( // all fields are passed as arguments to the constructor
        public name: string,
        public birthDate: Date
        public hobbies: Hobby[]
    ) {}
}
interface Hobby {
    hobby: string,
    startDate: Date
}

const person = new Person(
    'Bob',
    new Date('1998-10-21'),
    [
        {   hobby: 'programming',
            startDate: new Date('2021-01-01'),
        },
        {   hobby: 'cooking',
            startDate: new Date('2020-12-31'),
        },
    ]
);
const personJson = JSON.stringify(person);

const personReviver = Reviver.get(Person); //   extract the reviver from the class
const personFromJson = JSON.parse(personJson, personReviver);
```

Finally, let's use 2 classes :

```js
@Reviver<Hobby>({
    '.': ({hobby, startDate}) => new Hobby(hobby, startDate), //   instance builder
    startDate: Date
})
class Hobby {
    constructor (
        public hobby: string,
        public startDate: Date
    ) {}
}

@Reviver<Person>({
    '.': ({name, birthDate, hobbies}) => new Person(name, birthDate, hobbies), //   instance builder
    birthDate: Date,
    hobbies: {
        '*': Hobby  //   we can refer a class decorated with @Reviver
    }
})
class Person {
    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public birthDate: Date,
        public hobbies: Hobby[]
    ) {}
}

const person = new Person(
    'Bob',
    new Date('1998-10-21'),
    [
        new Hobby('programming', new Date('2021-01-01')),
        new Hobby('cooking', new Date('2020-12-31')
    ]
);
const personJson = JSON.stringify(person);

const personReviver = Reviver.get(Person); //   extract the reviver from the class
const personFromJson = JSON.parse(personJson, personReviver);
```