# Is there a way to return an JSON object back to it's js object form?

Tags: javascript, json, oop, object, p5.js

I am fiddling around with p5 and javascript data i/o. I have an array of objects that have complex structures and functions encapsulated inside. (Like my_object.parents is another array full of the exact kind of the my_object). I am trying to implement a save as json and load from that json mechanic to my project. But when i load a json, it is recognized as an generic(?) object. So my encapsulated functions fail to work. I tried to create a a temporary object and than copy the values into it but it is a pain in the arse when we have recursive arrays. Is there an easier way to cast/parse or just solve this problem.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `JSON.parse()` will get you `Object` of JSON. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: There are specialized JSON formats that 'remember' the type of object they were created from (by adding additional metadata to the JSON), yes. Search for "javascript json restore original objects".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14027168/2864740 (still manual though; not meta-based)

Comment: @user2864740 Exactly what i was looking for. Thank you Veeeery much.